# How to using preg_replace to change url link?

Tags: php

I have a url src:

```
$url = 'http://www.test.com/uploads/2013/06/test.jpg';
```

And mine code:

```
preg_replace('/-\d+x\d+(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$)/i', '-220x220', $url);
```

How to using `preg_replace` to result is

```
$url = 'http://www.test.com/uploads/2013/06/test-220x220.jpg';
```

Comment: Is the code supposed to always insert `-220x220` in between the file name and the extension?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to make the size part optional:

```
preg_replace('/(-\d+x\d+)?(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$)/i', '-220x220', $url);
```

[And that seems to work.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZlO4mQ)

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to just insert `'-220x220'` in between the file name and extension, you can use this:

```
$url = 'http://www.test.com/uploads/2013/06/test.jpg';

$file = pathinfo(basename($url));
if (in_array($file['extension'], array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif')) {
    $url = dirname($url) . '/' . $file['filename'] . '-220x220.' .$file['extension'];
}
```

See also: [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename), [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo)